# How to configure PhpStorm to use xdebug on a Vagrant machine

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, vagrantfile

I am trying to configure xdebug to work in PhpStorm with my Vagrant machine, but I cannot figure out how to properly configure everything.

Here is the Vagrantfile I am using: 
https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash

This Vagrantfile installs and configures xdebug for my Vagrant machine, but I'm not sure how to hook that up with PhpStorm. Between my xdebug.ini config, my web server config, and the PHP web app debug config, I cannot figure out how to get everything working.

[image: configurations]

When I click `run->debug` in PhpStorm, I get the following:

[image: result]

I have tried hacking away at the configuration details but have had 0 luck. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

xdebug runs "backwards" to most typical server software one would deal with on Vagrant. IE, for apache you would fire that up on the VM and forward a port from the host to the VM so you could hit the server. Well, xdebug wants to push data *from* the VM to the host machine. Which means you need to feed xdebug the host's IP address -- which is probably the one the VM configured on the host only network and not your typical IP address -- and also to make sure that xdebug server is running and can accept connections.

Yeah that leaves a bit to be desired . . . .